# Jquery In rails won't load for masonry

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can i load the jquery with rails. I have try in the following

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var $container = $('#container');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector: '.item'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

But i am getting an error. This is included in my html code. Not in the header. Now I come to realize when clicking on it i get the error route not set up. How can i load it the proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See application.js.

By default, jquery is part of rails starting from rails 3. You dont need to include it separately.